# How can I create an image overlay blend mode algorithm like on Photoshop?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photo, blending

I'm working on a code that should blend 2 images with each other.
The effect should be similar to Photoshop overlay blend mode or screen mode.

I tried the following algorithm, unfortunately it does not work:

```
n[c] = 255 - (((255 - n[c]) * (255 - o[c])) / 255);
n[c + 1] = 255 - (((255 - n[c + 1]) * (255 - o[c + 1])) / 255);
n[c + 2] = 255 - (((255 - n[c + 2]) * (255 - o[c + 2])) / 255);
```

The following algorithm works, but this is not the effect I need.
This effect is similar to Multiply Blend Mode

```
n[c]=n[c]*o[c]/255,
n[c+1]=n[c+1]*o[c+1]/255,
n[c+2]=n[c+2]*o[c+2]/255;
```

So, I need an algorithm that allows me to mix 2 images and get the effect like in Photoshop overlay or screen blend mode.

Thanks.

Comment: "unfortunately it does not work:" is not very specific. Does it give an error when you try to run it? Does it give the wrong result? I *think* you are looking for something like: `n[c] = 255 - ((1 - n[c] / 255) * (1 - (o[c] / 255) * 255)`